# How to use state in a component?

Tags: reactjs

I have my component and I want to use the `react-css-blur` (https://openbase.com/js/react-css-blur) componant inside mine. The problem is that I keep getting `state is not defined` and `blurOn is not defined` but I don't find how to fix this issue.

Here is my componant where I want to add `react-css-blur`:

```
import React from "react"
import Blur from 'react-css-blur'

const Card = ({ heading, paragraph, imgUrl, projectLink }) => {
  state = {
    blurOn: false
  }
  blurOn = (blurOn) => {
    this.setState({ blurOn });
  }
  
  return (
    <Blur radius={ this.state.blurOn ? '5px' : '0' } transition="400ms">
        <div
            className="card"
            style={{
                backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),url(" +imgUrl +")",
            }}
            onMouseEnter={ () => this.blurOn(true) }
            onMouseLeave={ () => this.blurOn(false) }
        >
            <div className="content">
                <h1 className="header" style={{color: "black", fontSize: 25}}>{heading}</h1>
                <p className="text" style={{color: "black", fontSize: 18}}>{paragraph}</p>
                <a
                    href={projectLink ? projectLink : "#"}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    className="btn"
                >
                    Explore
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Blur>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Comment: You have to use [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook since you are using a functional component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code seems to be a mixture of Class based component and functional component. it has to be either of one.

```js
// import React from "react"
// import Blur from 'react-css-blur'
// the code won't run because stackoverflow code snippet does not support
// latest version of react

const Card = ({ heading, paragraph, imgUrl, projectLink }) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    blurOn: false
  })
  const blurOn = (blurOn) => {
    setState({ blurOn });
  }
  
  return (
    <Blur radius={ state.blurOn ? '5px' : '0' } transition="400ms">
        <div
            className="card"
            style={{
                backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),url(" +imgUrl +")",
            }}
            onMouseEnter={ () => blurOn(true) }
            onMouseLeave={ () => blurOn(false) }
        >
            <div className="content">
                <h1 className="header" style={{color: "black", fontSize: 25}}>{heading}</h1>
                <p className="text" style={{color: "black", fontSize: 18}}>{paragraph}</p>
                <a
                    href={projectLink ? projectLink : "#"}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    className="btn"
                >
                    Explore
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Blur>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Card />, document.getElementById('root'))


// if you're using classic class based component

class Card2 extends React.Component {
  // { heading, paragraph, imgUrl, projectLink }
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { blurOn: false };
  }
  
  blurOn(blurOn) {
    this.setState({ blurOn });
  }
  render () {
  
  return (
    <Blur radius={ this.state.blurOn ? '5px' : '0' } transition="400ms">
        <div
            className="card"
            style={{
                backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),url(" +this.props.imgUrl +")",
            }}
            onMouseEnter={ () => this.blurOn(true) }
            onMouseLeave={ () => this.blurOn(false) }
        >
            <div className="content">
                <h1 className="header" style={{color: "black", fontSize: 25}}>{this.props.heading}</h1>
                <p className="text" style={{color: "black", fontSize: 18}}>{this.props.paragraph}</p>
                <a
                    href={this.props.projectLink ? this.props.projectLink : "#"}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    className="btn"
                >
                    Explore
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Blur>
  )
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- just ignore this react version. code snippet won't run -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you are using function instead of class component.
You will either have to convert to Class component - as it's in this example https://openbase.com/js/react-css-blur, or you  will have to use useState() hook.

Here is example with `useState()`

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Card = ({ heading, paragraph, imgUrl, projectLink }) => {
  const [blurOn, setBlurOn] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <Blur radius={blurOn ? '5px' : '0'} transition="400ms">
        <div
            className="card"
            style={{
                backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),url(" +imgUrl +")",
            }}
            onMouseEnter={ () => setBlurOn(true) }
            onMouseLeave={ () => setBlurOn(false) }
        >
            <div className="content">
                <h1 className="header" style={{color: "black", fontSize: 25}}>{heading}</h1>
                <p className="text" style={{color: "black", fontSize: 18}}>{paragraph}</p>
                <a
                    href={projectLink ? projectLink : "#"}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                    className="btn"
                >
                    Explore
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Blur>
  )
}

export default Card
```

Answer (score 1):

Either use Class-based components or hooks. For fixing your issue you can use a Class-based component too.

simply change

```
const Card = ({ heading, paragraph, imgUrl, projectLink }) => {
```

to

```
class Card extends React.Component {
{heading,paragraph,imgUrl,projectLink}=props
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {blurOn:false};
```

or use Hooks
[Introducing Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)
for using state on hooks
[Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)